# Can one set an iframe's src and manipulate its contents afterwards?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

My goal is to have a parent page change the src of an iframe from blank to its proper url (as to utilize an onload handler in the iframe at a given point, but that's beside the point) and then manipulate the iframe's contents. However, javascript seems oblivious to any elements of an iframe that aren't on its src when the DOM loads. Is there any way around this?

The setTimeouts are intended to allow the DOM and iframe to load.
edit:fixed some stuff.
Here's the containing page:

```
<html><head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var done = false;
        var theIframe;
        window.onload = function () {
            setTimeout('stuff()', 2000);
            clearTimeout('stuff()');
        }

        function stuff() {
            if (!done) {
                theIframe = window.myiframe;
                theIframe.src = 'http://localhost/TestStuff/redirectIframe.jsp';
                done = true;
                stuff();
            } else {
                theIframe.setMe = true;
            }
        }

      </script>
</head>
      <body>
      <iframe src="" width="500" height="500" id="myiframe" name="myiframe">

      </iframe>
      </body>
```

And here's the iframe:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var setMe = false;
        window.onload = setInterval('checker()', 1000);
        function checker() {
            alert('hi');
            if (setMe) {
                window.onload = null;
                top.location = 'http://www.google.com';
                alert('foundit');
            }  else alert('a');

        }

    </script>
    </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In this piece of code:

```
theIframe.src = ...;
stuff();
```

you're calling `stuff()` immediately, contrary to what you have described, so in fact you're not allowing any time for the page to load. Maybe you're confused about how `setTimeout` works: it just schedules a single execution after the specified time, it doesn't automatically delay all calls to a function.

Also, you can use `clearTimeout` only with a previous ID returned by `setTimeout`, not with code as you have now.

Try something like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
  loadFrame();
}

function loadFrame() {
  theIframe = ...;
  theIframe.src = ...;
  setTimeout(setSomething, 2000);
}

function setSomething() {
  theIframe.setMe = true;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, there wasn't much point to that recursion I suppose. Even with the above, though, theIframe.contentWindow is undefined after the src change.

Comment: @Rujiel: That's strange -- that shouldn't happen if the page has indeed completed loading.

Comment: Can't access anything in the iframe's js if I had to modify the src first. Seems only the DOM will update on an iframe refesh, and js on the iframe won't be taken into account?